# Android gradle build error "Could not find <dependency>"

Tags: android, bitbucket, build.gradle, react-native

In my project there is a module which requires a dependency which is located in bitbucket. When i try building it cant find the dependency. Where am i wrong?

error:

```
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugApk'.
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-mqtt-iot'.
Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':react-native-mqtt- iot:_debugPublishCopy'.
Could not find co.ibhubs.ibchat:ibchat:0.0.1. Required by:project :react-native-mqtt-iot
```

`build.gradle` file

```
def computeVersionName() {
    // dynamically retrieve version from package.json
    def slurper = new JsonSlurper()
    def json = slurper.parse(file('../package.json'), "utf-8")
    return json.version
}

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
        classpath "org.jfrog.buildinfo:build-info-extractor-gradle:3.1.1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26

    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        // get version name from package.json version
        versionName computeVersionName()
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" } // All of React Native (JS, Android binaries) is installed from npm
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.facebook.react:react-native:+'
    compile('co.ibhubs.ibchat:ibchat:0.0.1') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.commons', module: 'commons-io'
    }
    compile files('libs/ib_chat-0.0.29.jar')
}
```

Comment: Apart from the solution, you need to move over to newer versions of Gradle. 'Compile' is deprecated and you may need to consider using 'implementation' as part of newer gradle versions.

Comment: @Dinesh. Yup its a very old project. I tried upgrading it but got so many issues. For now i just wan to run it like this only.